# Secuirty related certification/training for .NET Developers

Tags: .net, professional-education, asp.net, certification, angularjs

I would like to know if there are any Free certifications related to writing secure code that myself and our team of .NET/AngularJS web-developers take up,

So that we can write secure code and also assure our customers that the developers of their app are 'Certified'

I am mainly looking for Free (If none Payed is also fine) internet based Certification .

I did google around for the same (and know about OWASP, isc2.org, sans.org) but couldn't tell which one is free, or industry best.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Except for "which one is free", this is up to opinion, and will quickly change over time. And basically, this is a question for Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by forgetting all about (ISC)² and SANS, their certifications are quite expensive.

However, it does not answer your question for an *Certification* but I suggest you have a look at:

- OWASP Secure Coding Practices https://www.owasp.org/images/0/08/OWASP_SCP_Quick_Reference_Guide_v2.pdf
- OWASP Security Knowledge Framework https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Security_Knowledge_Framework

You can also arrange CTF competitions using OWASP Shepherd or Facebook CTF where the developers can get hands-on experience with common vulnerabilities.